# Update colour of plot in 3d matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, 3d

I want to create an animated scatter plot in 3D, where the latest point is shown in a certain colour and then grays out, as far as the next point is generated.

The input file 'coordinates.txt' simply includes the x, y and z values in three columns.

The code works, as long as I skip the z value and just use a 2d projection. When I am adding the z coordinate I get a `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`.

I don't understand why I get this error for the 3d but not for the 2d projection and why it wants to calculate len() in the 3d version.

I would be happy, if somebody could help me to figure this out!

```
input_file = open('coordinates.txt', 'r').readlines()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

pylab.xlim([0,6])
pylab.ylim([0,6])
ax.set_zlim([0,6])


line = None

def main(i):
    global line
    if line is not None: 
        line.set_color('gray')
    line, = ax.plot(x,y,z, 'ro')

for row in input_file: 
    el = row.split()
    x = float(el[0])
    y = float(el[1])
    z = float(el[2])

    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, main)
    plt.draw()
```

Here the entire traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./def_func_3d.py", line 65, in 
>       ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, main)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1010, in   **init**
>       TimedAnimation.**init**(self, fig, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 864, in   **init**
>       *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 545, in   **init**
>       self._init_draw()
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1035, in   _init_draw
>       self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1049, in   _draw_frame
>       self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
>     File "./def_func_3d.py", line 43, in main
>       line, = ax.plot(x,y,z, 'ro')
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line  1511, in plot
>       zs = np.ones(len(xs)) * zs
>   TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Can you include the entire error traceback? Looking at where the error occurs will help.

Comment: Thanks, I added the entire traceback in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot` is expecting iterables for `x` and `y`, which it uses to size `z` if it is a scalar.  It should be fine if you change the code to

```
line, = ax.plot([x], [y], z, 'ro')
```